# How to kill a windows application using TideSDK?

Tags: windows, cmd, tidesdk

i am trying to run a command like `TASKKILL /F /IM notepad.exe`

```
var process = Ti.Process.createProcess({args: ['TASKKILL /F /IM notepad.exe']});
process.launch();
```

or

```
Ti.Process.launch('TASKKILL /F /IM skype.exe');
```

the debugger doesn't say much, just `Error launching 'TASKKILL /F /IM notepad.exe'`

[documentation](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.Process-method-createProcess)

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create process I use this syntax (coffeeScript) :

```
customProcess = Ti.Process.createProcess([
  arg1
  arg2
  arg3
])
customProcess.launch()
```

Here is an example of how I use Ti.Process : executing the wkhtmltopdf binary in order to create a pdf from HTML/CSS. So I use the following :

```
pdfProcess = Ti.Process.createProcess([
   Ti.API.application.getResourcesPath() + '/wkhtmltopdf/builds/win32/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
   '--margin-bottom'
   30
   '--margin-top'
   40
   sourcePath
   '--header-html'
   headerPath
   '--footer-html'
   footerPath
   destinationPath
])
pdfProcess.launch()
```

I haven't tried but maybe the following will work :

```
exitProcess = Ti.Process.createProcess([
    'TASKKILL'
    '/F'
    '/IM'
    'notepad.exe'
])
exitProcess.launch()
```

I think you'll have to split each argument of your process in a item of a list.

Comment: i end up using python

    `<script type="text/python">
        import os
        os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM notepad.exe')
    </script>`